# Sorting the django objects based on SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer, django-jsonfield

I am trying to order the user profiles based on the timestamp of the last message in between both the users.

I am using SerializerMethodField to get the timestamp of the last message.

is there any way I can sort the data?

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lastmessage = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id','lastmessage']
    def get_lastmessage(self,obj): 
        k = self.context.get('view').kwargs['sid']
        data =( Message.objects.filter(receiver=obj.id,sender=k) | Message.objects.filter(sender=obj.id,receiver=k)).order_by('-timestamp').values('message','timestamp')
        if len(data) == 0:
            return ""
        else:
            data = data.first()
            data["timestamp"] = str(data["timestamp"])
        return str(data)
```

My view:

```
   class UserChatViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
       queryset = User.objects.all() 
       serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

Now my views return:

```
[{
    "id": 4,
    "lastmessage": "{'message': 'random', 'timestamp': '2020-06-14 23:49:33.077749+00:00'}"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "lastmessage": ""
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "lastmessage": "{'message': 'sample', 'timestamp': '2020-06-14 11:53:03.880833+00:00'}"
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "lastmessage": ""
}]
```

But I want it to sort based on the timestamp of last message

Comment: can you post your views get_queryset  method

Comment: ```class UserChatViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite `list` in order to achieve this:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().list(request, args, kwargs)
    # sort response.data['results']
    return response
```

Also, `lastmessage` can be a `dict` instead of a `str`, so it's easier to work with.

Comment: This will work but as you saw in my output there are some empty values for the last message which is causing an error in sorting

Comment: For the "# sort response.data['results']" line, I used the following `sorted_data = sorted(response.data, key=lambda k: k["last_message"]["timestamp"], reverse=True)` then `response.data = sorted_data    return response`.  (Note this only works if there are no null values in timestamp.)

Answer (score 1):

The order of your response should be handled in the view .

```
  from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
 lm = Message.objects.filter(sender=OuterRef("id"), receiver=self.kwargs['sid']).order_by('-timestamp')   
    data = User.objects.all().annotate(
        lastmessage=Subquery(
                    lm.values('timestamp')[:1]
                )
    ).order_by('-lastmessage__timestamp')
```

Comment: This Is returning: 'Subquery' object has no attribute 'order_by'

Comment: Now this gives: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.

Comment: Same error. and I think it should be .```order_by('-lastmessage__timestamp')``` instead of ```order_by('-last_message__timestamp')```

Comment: thats corrected, but error is different @saibhaskar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216963/discussion-between-saibhaskar-and-mohit-harshan).